# WebRTC: How can I make users join a room and watch my live video without them having to create an "answer" or turning their webcam on?

Tags: webrtc

I'm new to WebRTC and I've learned that in order to establish a connection between two peers or more you have to create an offer and the other peers must send you back an answer (while exporting their local stream).

How can I make users join a room and watch my live video without them having to create an "answer" or turning their webcam on?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Just to clarify, I'm familiar with the WebRTC flow behind the scenes (signaling, offer/answer etc). All I want to know based on that logic, is how can I "stream" my video to another user, so they don't have to stream their own video as well (I only want them to be able to watch MY video, without asking them for webcam permissions)

Comment: It would help if you wrote a so-called "Chat server" to exchange the offer and answer. To join a room, you may refer to the express rest API to do so.

Comment: I know about the "behind the scenes" process.
My point is: all the tutorials I have watched showed me that there's always an offer from peer X and an answer from peer Y, but what if I only want to stream live video to others? How does the "offer/answer" logic take place here?

Comment: You may refer to the following web page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling

Comment: I read it, it still doesn't answer my question. I only want to transmit my video from my peer to other peers. I don't want other peers to send me their data. I only want them to connect and watch my own video (That should be a default state, until one of the "viewers" want to send their data as well, but it's irrelevant for now).

Comment: Regardless of establishing data or video connections, both need to go through the specified process.

Comment: So if someone doesn't have a webcam and I still want them to be able to watch me without prompting for webcam access, should I not use WebRTC here?
That is so weird.

Comment: The remote peer does not have to have a webcam. You can use WebRTC also.

Comment: OK, so could you please explain how can I achieve that? Because in every place I've checked I saw that each participant has to send offer/answer in order to establish the connection and that means that I always have to ask for webcam permissions from the other user even if I don't want them to stream their video.

In another place I've checked, someone suggested to get only the audio from user X and not adding tracks to the peer connection on their side, but that means I will still have to ask for permissions from user X and that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Asking permission from the user is the essential process,you cannot avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

To create a WebRTC connection you always have to generate and exchange the offer and answer, there's no way around that.

But: this does not require any special permissions and thus does not prompt the user for any access.

What *does* cause a permission request prompt are the calls accessing media like [`getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) or [`getDisplayMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia). If you want to prevent the permission request dialogs simply skip calls to these functions in your code - at least on the user-side, the presenter of course still has to grant permissions to share their video.

WebRTC itself does not require any media streams to establish a connection. For a text only example see [this demo in the WebRTC repo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/datachannel/channel/).